# Uses of averaging an operator over the elements of a finite group?

Tags: group-theory

In my so far brief journey into group theory, I've encountered a few different situations where it is helpful to average some operator over the elements of the group.

For example:

1. To classify finite subgroups of the isometry group of the plane, we pick a point $a$ and define $c = \frac{1}{|G|} \Sigma_{T \in G} T(a)$. Then $c$ is the centroid of $a$ - the average of the vectors in the orbit. Since this is a fixed point, and since $G$ is finite, it is easy to show that $G$ is either a dihedral group or a cyclic group, depending on whether or not it contains orientation reversing isometries.
2. In order to prove Mashke's theorem in representation theory, we produce an inner product compatible with a group action, in the sense that it will give us a $G$-invariant complement to a $G$-invariant subspace. Given any Hermitian form $\langle, \rangle$, we define this new inner product by $\langle \langle x,y \rangle \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \Sigma_{g \in G} \langle gx, gy \rangle$.
3. Similarly, given a map $\phi: V \to W$, $V$ and $W$ representations of a finite group $G$, we can average $\phi$ to obtain a $G$-linear map. $\phi(x) = \Sigma_{g \in G} g \phi (g^{-1} x)$
4. The number of orbits of the action of a finite group on a finite set is given as the average of the permutation character.

Can anyone suggest other interesting or notable uses of this idea?

Comment: Do you know any algebraic topology? You can use exactly the same sorts of averaging arguments to relate the (co)homology of a space $X$ and a quotient $X/G$ of it by the action of a finite group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think I see that, but there is a gap in my argument: Coefficients in $Q$, $q: X \to X/G$ a quotient. $q_{chain} : C_n(X) \to C_n(X/G)$ is surj. as $\pi_1(\Delta^n) = 0$. For $\sigma : \Delta^n \to X$, define $ m(\sigma) = 1/|G| \Sigma g_{chain} \sigma $. With $q$ and $q \circ m$ we get a commutative triangle of chain complexes, which turns into a commutative triangle in homology. There $q_* : im(m) : C_n(X/G)$ gains inj., (at least I think so - can you help?). Thus(?), $H_n(X/G) \cong (1/|G| \Sigma_{g \in G} g_*) (H_n(X))$. Checks out for projective space as $S^n / Z_2$...

Comment: You can find the argument in Hatcher (search for "transfer homomorphism," I think). Of course you need to work over a ground ring in which $|G|$ is invertible; the conclusion fails in general, e.g. you don't get the correct integral or $\mathbb{F}_2$-homology or cohomology of projective space this way.